# keras data augmented cnn always expect a single neuron in the classifier output?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am implementing a two class cnn with data augmentation, however the network always raises an 'expected shape error' all the time unless the output layer consists of a single neuron. Here is my code.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D , Flatten, Dropout
import keras
from keras import losses
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread, imshow, subplots, show
import numpy as np


def my_model(input_shape, opt, no_of_class):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(no_of_class, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model

PATH="C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\****\\****\\data\\poroxity\\"
train_data=PATH+'train'
validation_data=PATH+'validation'
no_of_class=2
training_samples=251
validation_samples=108
epochs=50
batch_size=16
img_width, img_height = 224, 224
opt = Adam(lr=0.001)

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=90,
        vertical_flip=True,
        width_shift_range=0.3, fill_mode='wrap',
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
validation_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# validation and training iterators preparing loaded images from the directory
train_it = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    class_mode='binary',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    color_mode='rgb',
    seed=42,
    save_to_dir=PATH+'augmented',
    save_prefix='poroxity_aug',
    save_format='jpeg'
    )
validation_it = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    class_mode='binary',
    batch_size=1)

model=my_model(input_shape, opt, no_of_class)
model.fit_generator(
        generator=train_it,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=1,
        steps_per_epoch=train_it.n // train_it.batch_size,
        validation_data=validation_it,
        validation_steps=validation_it.n // validation_it.batch_size,
        )
```

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Some outputs

Found 251 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 108 images belonging to 2 classes.
train batch shape:  (16, 224, 224, 3)
label batch shape:  (16,)
labels in the batch:  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
validation batch shape:  (1, 224, 224, 3)
label batch shape:  (1,)
labels in the batch:  [0.]
input shape:  (224, 224, 3)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting loss in model.compile as 'categorical_crossentropy' and class_mode both in .flow_from_directory of train and validation as 'categorical'.